# Threads, processes and Application.Exit()

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, process

My application consists of main message loop (GUI) and threads (Task.Factory).

In the threads I call some 3rd party applications with `var p = new Process();`

But when I invoke `Application.Exit();` in the message loop - I can see that the processes, that were started in the threads are still in the memory and are being executed.

So the question is - how to kill all the threads and Processes right after `Application.Exit();` has been invoked?

**UPD**:

old:

```
p.WaitForExit();
```

new:

```
while (!p.WaitForExit(1000))
{
    if (FlagToExit)
    {
        p.Kill();
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handle the [`Application.ApplicationExit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.applicationexit.aspx) event.

Comment: So I just need to create some boolean flag that i need to observe in the threads and when it becomes true (i will assign it true on `Application.ApplicationExit` event) - then Terminate processes?

Comment: I've added update, about how I expect to implement it. Please criticize it.

Answer (score 8):

Simply try this

when you create a thread make it background thread

```
Thread.IsBackground = true;
```

and on `Application.Exit();`

all thread will be closed

Comment: -1: This does not terminate child processes, which is half of the op's question.

Answer (score 1):

Process are created independent of the parent process.

The best solution is to create a signal for the child processes and have them exit when it is signalled, gracefully shutting them down.

If the processes are outside of your control, then you'll have to use `Process.CloseMainWindow` and `Process.Kill` to kill them when your parent process is ready to exit.

Comment: It would. I had done a search using the traditional name of `Terminate`, so I missed the `Kill` method. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because all of your threads are `Foreground`. And a `Foreground` thread (GUI) can't terminate another `Foreground` thread. So you just need to mark your new threads as `Background` and so give new threads a dependency to your `Foreground` thread (GUI).
If you want to mark a thread as `Background` thread you just need to add this to your code:

```
p.IsBackground = true;
```

Comment: By this, you don't need using Application.ApplicationExit anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class calling the process and terminate it on it's dispose.

Answer (score -1):

Use Invoke() and run the Application.Exit() command inside like this:

```
this.Invoke((Action)delegate ()
{
    Application.Exit();
});
```