# Does Application.Exit() kill background threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, application-shutdown

I created a form which runs multiple background threads. I added another class which handles exceptions and errors if any. When the code runs, if an error occurs that should force the application to close can I just use `Application.Exit()`? Will that kill the background threads as well?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689564/threads-processes-and-application-exit

Comment: Do you want to kill the background threads or not?

Comment: Also, why are you asking us?  Why not just run it and see for yourself.

Comment: @Servy why don't you tell him where to observe running background threads ?

Comment: He doesn't need to know if there are running background threads, he needs to know if the process is still running or not.  Task Manager can tell you that, or if you're debugging in VS the IDE will be in debug mode until the process terminates.  If it goes away the threads finished or were killed.  If it doesn't, there are foreground threads keeping the process open.

Comment: @Servy well excuse me I am new to C# and was just asking to be sure I will not have any threads running after my app exists.  You could have put your last comment first instead of "why are you asking us"

Comment: And Zimdanen thanks for the link.

Comment: Your post didn't seem to imply that you were incapable of determining if background threads were running.  Had that been a part of the question, or had you asked, I would have told you how to check.  I also asked why you didn't just run it because the answers you were given were wrong, and I *know* that other answerers are capable of a simple test to find out the answer.

Comment: Also note that link is largely talking about processes, not threads, which are very different.  Make sure you don't confuse the two.

Comment: Servy I know that the background threads are running.  I wanted to know if I exit the application before the background thread is complete will the background thread continue or will it terminate.  Anyway thanks Servy I was just having a bad and long day at work.  Now to be safe can I say that the difference between process and threads is that process run in their own memory space and threads run in shared memory space.

Answer (score 6):

No, it will not. Application.Exit() will simply force the windows message pump to post a Quit message, which will terminate your application's main thread. However, the process itself will continue to run until the background threads complete.

**Update**: as commenters have correctly pointed out, if your thread's IsBackground property is set to True, terminating the main thread via Application.Exit() will shut down the process.

Comment: Other foreground threads will keep the process from terminating, background threads will not.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought *background* threads(i.e. those with `IsBackground == true` don't prevent the application from terminating, and get force terminated on shutdown.

Comment: Thanks so no need to worry when I use the Application.Exit all background threads will terminate

Comment: If you're using `ThreadPool` then, `IsBackground` will be initialize to `true` for you, so they won't keep the application from stopping.

Comment: On WinCE8/CF3.9, even setting IsBackground=true does not allow the Thread to be stopped by Application.Exit().
The only clean and universal way, which is working whatever the OS and the Framework, is to define a flag in the Thread to cope with the graceful ending, and to position this flag to True just before executing Application.Exit().

Answer (score 0):

No. Thread termination is cooperative.